# rails:how to create dynamic drop-down box in rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

```
class FeedbacksController < ApplicationController
    def new
    @feedback = Feedback.new
    @subject = Subject.find_all_by_teacher_id(current_user.id)
end

end
```

Here is view,
    
      
        <%= form_for(@feedback) do |f| %>
         <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
      <%= f.label :subject_id %>
      <%= f.collection_select(:subject_id, @subject, :id, :name ) %>

```
  <%= f.label :strengths %>
  <%= f.text_field :strengths %>

  <%= f.label :rating %>
  <%= f.radio_button :rating, 'A', :checked => true %> A
  <%= f.radio_button :rating, 'B' %> B
  <%= f.radio_button :rating, 'C' %> C
  <%= f.radio_button :rating, 'D' %> D



  <%= f.label :recommendations %>
  <%= f.text_field :recommendations %>






  <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

I wanna to create a second drop-down box if chose a subject ,system will search students who have this subject from DB.That meaning when I choose another subject this drop-down box will also change

Comment: Not sure if I am following your example. Would it be something like (in the context of states and cities) - If I choose a state the next dropdown box populates with all the cities within that state?

Comment: You could checkout the railscast on the Dynamic Select Menus. That should point you in the general direction. http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Say for example I have a **Country** table which contains names of
>   countries, and I am creating a form for user. In the form I need all
>   countries name should come dynamically from database, and I will
>   use all names as **Options** in **Select**

**When I am using in form for creating a new user, I will use:**

```
%label COUNTRY
      =f.select :user_country, options_for_select(Country.order(:country_name).pluck(:country_name))
```

**When I am using in form for editing an existing user, I will use:**

```
%label COUNTRY
  =f.select :user_country, options_for_select(Country.order(:country_name).pluck(:country_name), :selected=>@user.user_country)
```